# IBM MQ user access permission: put/get messages on a queue

Tags: authorization, ibm-mq

How do I set MQ permissions for a windows user (username and password)
to be able to use a queue, so a java client can get and put messages ?

I already have a queue manager up and listening on (windows) port 1414 on locallost and a queue defined.

Comment: Google the `SET AUTHREC` MQSC command or the `setmqaut` command.

Comment: You may find this page in IBM Docs useful. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=programs-configuring-queue-manager-accept-client-connections-multiplatforms

Comment: If you have problems, remember to look in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG and update your question to tell us whether your windows user id is a privileged user or not (e.g. mqm group, administrator etc).

Comment: Nice link @MoragHughson.  Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Hello Morag, your link to the IBM doc was perfect! THANKS!!! But, don't you think the number of steps/commands in the doc was a lot? Shouldn't it be easier/quicker to authorize a single non-privileged user??? Seems that you need to give user, privilege to the channel, queue manager and queue to each? Rgds, Jim.

Comment: Hi @JImG. MQ security is quite granular I'll give you that :-) However, some of the steps are only needed the first time the user gains access to the queue manager, and then when you need to add an extra queue, you don't have to do the whole lot again.